# Удаление дубликатов слов из вводимой строки с клавиатуры python

Tags: python, строки, клавиатура, повторы

Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры строку через пробел, необходимо удалить дубликат слова и вывести каждое оставшееся слово с новой строки. Сам очень туп. Всё что нашел на просторах инета вот

```
s = input()
s_new = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s_new.find(s[i]) == -1 and s[i] != ' ':
        s_new += s[i]
print(s_new)
```

Да,знаю там ещё и пробелы удаляются,но хотел это как-то на новую строку изменить не вышло, каждый раз ошибку выдаёт

Comment: порядок вывода слов имеет значение?

Answer (score 1):

Простой вариант, если не важен порядок вывода:

```
s = input()
for i in set(s.split(" ")) - {" ", ""}:
    print(i)
```

Можно еще так:

```
import re

s = input()
for i in set(re.split(" +", s.strip())):
    print(i)
```

Но лучше с такими вопросами разбираться самостоятельно, уж больно много информации об этом. Обычно с таким не помогают.

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать так

```
a = input().split(" ")
a = list(set(a))
print("\n".join(a))
```

Или в сокращенном варианте этот же пример вот так

```
print("\n".join(list(set(input().split(" ")))))
```

если важен порядок то можно импортировать модуль `itertools`

```
from itertools import groupby
a = input().split(" ")
a = [l for l, _ in groupby(a)]
print("\n".join(a))
```

или сокращенно

```
from itertools import groupby
print("\n".join([l for l, _ in groupby(input().split(" "))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот мои пара вариантов, в первом случае порядок слов не соблюдается в выводе, во втором случае все слова в том же порядке. Первый вариант:

```
s = str(input())
s_arr = s.split()
s_set = set(s_arr)
s_no_dubl = "\n".join(s_set)
print(s_no_dubl)
```

Второй вариант:

```
s = str(input())
s_arr = s.split()
s_no_dubl = []
for word in s_arr:
    if not (word in s_no_dubl):
        s_no_dubl.append(word)
s_finall = "\n".join(s_no_dubl)
print(s_finall)
```